# Android Hello World orients from portrait to landscape but not vice versa

Tags: android

I created the Hello World android application, which is automatically created by the ADT plugin for eclipse. I noticed that when I reorient in the emulator, the hello world application properly automatically reorients from portrait to landscape, but not the other way. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with recent editions of the emulator. It is not a problem with your code. You will need to cause some other program to take over the screen, then return to your app. For example, you can press the green call button to simulate placing a phone call, then press BACK.